# TypeError: on_voice_state_update() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

> Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "C:\Users\vitak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py",
> line 343, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs) TypeError: on_voice_state_update() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

**How to solve this problem? I've been trying for 2 weeks. But I still could not understand what 4th argument the function receives**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from pymongo import MongoClient
# from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle
from datetime import datetime
import time
import os


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
cluster = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
colluser = cluster.chill.user
collclan = cluster.chill.clans
collshop = cluster.chill.shop


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    # DiscordComponents(client)
    print("Bot connected to the server")
    # post2 = {

    # }

    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            post = {
                "_id": member.id,
                "name": member.mention,
                "user": member.name,
                "inventory": [],
                "warms": 0,
                "mute": 0,
                "voice_activ": 0,
                "localban": 0,
                "register": member.created_at,
                "onservfrom": member.joined_at,
                "clan": 0,
                "marry": 0,
                "love": 0,
                "childs": [],
                "balance": 0,
                "bank": 0,
                "rep": 0,
                "cdxp": 0,
                "cnxp": 0,
                "dxp": 0,
                "nxp": 0,
                "cdbal": 0,
                "cdlvl": 1,
                "cnlvl": 1,
                "dlvl": 1,
                "nlvl": 1
            }

            if colluser.count_documents({"_id": member.id}) == 0:
                colluser.insert_one(post)

@client.event
async def on_guild_role_create(role):
    print("new role created")
    # print(f"{role.id}")
    # print(f"{role.name}")
    post = {
        "_id": role.id,
        "titel": "none",
        "cp": [],
        "exp": 0,
        "lvl": 0,
        "maxcp": 7,
        "bank": 0
    }

    if collclan.count_documents({"role_id": role.id}) == 0:
        collclan.insert_one(post)

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    data = colluser.find_one({"_id": member.id})
    day = data["dxp"]
    dark = data["nxp"]
    dl = data["dlvl"]
    nl = data["nlvl"]
    dexp = 500 + 100 * dl
    nexp = 500 + 100 * nl
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        print("1")
        t1 = time.time()
        colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
            {"$set": {"voice_tim1": t1}})
    elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
        dtn = datetime.today().strftime("%I:%M %p")
        t1 = data["voice_tim1"]
        voice_activ1 = data["voice_activ"]
        balance = data["balance"]
        t2 = time.time()
        tim = t2-t1
        print("0")
        print(dtn)
        colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
            {"$set": {"voice_activ": voice_activ1 + tim}})
        colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
            {"$set": {"balance": balance + tim / 30}})
        if any(("AM" in dtn) for AM in dtn):
            print("time is AM")
            colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
                {"$set": {"dxp": day + tim / 4}})
        if any(("PM" in dtn) for PM in dtn):
            print("time is PM")
            colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
                {"$set": {"nxp": dark + tim / 4}})
        if data["dxp"] >= 500 + 100 * dl:
            colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
                {"$set": {"dlvl": dl + 1}})
            colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
                {"$set": {"dxp": day - dexp}})
        if data["nxp"] >= 500 + 100 * nl:
            colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
                {"$set": {"nlvl": nl + 1}})
            colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
                {"$set": {"nxp": dark - nexp}})


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    post = {
        "_id": member.id,
        "name": member.mention,
        "user": member.name,
        "inventory": [],
        "warms": 0,
        "mute": 0,
        "voice_activ": 0,
        "localban": 0,
        "register": member.created_at,
        "onservfrom": member.joined_at,
        "clan": 0,
        "marry": 0,
        "love": 0,
        "childs": [],
        "balance": 0,
        "bank": 0,
        "xp": 0,
        "dxp": 0,
        "nxp": 0,
        "cdbal": 0,
        "lvl": 1,
        "dlvl": 1,
        "nlvl": 1
    }

    if colluser.count_documents({"_id": member.id}) == 0:
        colluser.insert_one(post)


@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    print(error)

    if isinstance(error, commands.UserInputError):
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"Правильное использование команды: `{ctx.prefix}{ctx.command.name}` ({ctx.command.brief}): `{ctx.prefix}{ctx.command.usage}`"
        ))


@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")


@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")


@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
    client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")


for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")


client.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: How about you temporarily change the prototype to `async def on_voice_state_update(*args):`, and then `print(*args)`?

Comment: MAGIC#7777 <VoiceState self_mute=False self_deaf=False self_stream=False suppress=False requested_to_speak_at=None channel=<VoiceChannel id=858506956963577866 name='Временный войс' rtc_region=None position=1 bitrate=64000 user_limit=0 category_id=831879379939229798>> <VoiceState self_mute=False self_deaf=False self_stream=False suppress=False requested_to_speak_at=None channel=None>

Comment: That looks like three arguments to me. Not sure what to tell you.

Comment: The documentation says that there are only 3 arguments. But for some reason he gets 4.
And he receives them both on my computer and on the server.

It means that there is an error somewhere in the code or in the smom function call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the function was called by another 1 module, because of which there was a conflict of 2 identical functions